I suppose she would be/would have been about 40 years old when she died

I suppose she would be about 40 years old when she died.

[From an English-Japanese dictionary.]
Is it possible to replace would be with would have been?

I would use would have been in this context.

Do you think would be is wrong? When I first saw the sentence, I thought would be was wrong.

@Kaguyahime It's hard to say it's flat-out wrong without context. You can usually come up with some niche scenario where "would be" is correct. If I was speaking about a fictional character who lives to the end of the book but the author gives a fictional death date for her in an appendix, "she would be... when she died" might be correct. But yes, for a scenario like "I see a tombstone, and I calculate how old the person was when they died" would be seems wrong to me.

@Kaguyahime would be feels wrong

Yes. Actually it's preferable:

I suppose she would have been about 40 years old when she died.


Presumably you didn't mean to include the 'be'?

Thanks for that -- I fixed it!
